# VS Code SyntaxError: invalid syntax File "<stdin>", line 1

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner with VS Code, Done new installation and facing following problem:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/python1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/python1.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("hhi")
hhi
>>> & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/python1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/python1.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/python1.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/python/python1.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print("hi")
hi
>>>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to evaluate a `&`?

Comment: Is this a syntax error in VSCode or python?

Comment: its a sytax error in VSCODE

Comment: "&" i have not given anywhere where from vscode is picking i dont know

Answer (score 14):

It's happening because you didn't exit the Python REPL before trying to send commands to the terminal. Exit the REPL (`exit()` works), and then you will be back at your terminal and those commands will start working.